# How can one apply a quartz filter to the screen? (like invert colors)

Tags: macos

Just like how one can invert the colors of the screen with the accessibility preferences, how would one put other filters like the ones in /System/Library/Compositions such as 'Color Pencil' or 'Comic Book'?

Also, would it be possible to do this in an applescript? (and make it a shortcut as well)